# Ungroup after grouping by just one variable in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a lot of units that are measured repeated times.

```
>df
Item value  year
1     20     1990
1     20     1991
2     30     1990
2     15     1990
2     5      1991
3     10     1991
4     15     1990
5     10     1991
5      5     1991
```

I am trying to use `dplyr` to remove values that have a low number of observations. On this toy data, lets say that I want to remove data which has fewer than 2 counts.

```
>df <- df %>% 
  group_by(Item) %>% 
  tally() %>% 
  filter(n>1)

Item  n
1     2
2     3
5     2
```

The problem is that I would like to expand this back to what it was, but with this filter. I attempted using the `ungroup` command, but that seems to only have an effect when grouping by two variables. How can I filter by item counts then get my original variables back i.e `value` and `year`. It should look like this:

```
>df
Item value  year
1     20     1990
1     20     1991
2     30     1990
2     15     1990
2     5      1991
5     10     1991
5      5     1991
```

Comment: Try using `add_tally()` instead. Or just `filter(n() > 1)` after `group_by()`.

Comment: @AndreyKolyadin - you should add that as the answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

More simply, use dplyr's `row_number()`

```
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table("clipboard", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df %>% 
  group_by(Item) %>% 
  filter(max(row_number()) > 1) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   Item [3]
   Item value  year
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1    20  1990
2     1    20  1991
3     2    30  1990
4     2    15  1990
5     2     5  1991
6     5    10  1991
7     5     5  1991
```

Comment: You can use `n()` instead of `max(row_number())`